# Happy 2017 Sudoku

Tags: no-computers, sudoku, seasonal

This is a simple Sudoku. The only thing different from a regular sudoku are the symbols used: HAPY2017*. The snowflakes (a.k.a. asterisk) are like any other character.

[image]

Wishing you a Happy New Year 2017 and have fun solving puzzles!

---

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #23: Seasonal](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5704/fortnightly-topic-challenge-23-seasonal)</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I put it into excel and solved it from there:

> [image]

The step by step solution below is made up of 54 'moves' so I will write them in batches of 6 moves, giving the 9 steps below:

1.

> ```
> .1..A.*Y7
> *HY0.7.1A
> ...1*.0..
> .....2.7.
> ..H.Y.A..
> .0.P.....
> ..P......
> .A.Y.1..P
> H2.A7..*.
> ```

2.

> ```
> .1.2AH*Y7
> *HY0.7.1A
> ...1*Y0..
> .....2.7.
> ..H.Y.A..
> .0.P.....
> ..P....A.
> .A*Y.1..P
> H2.A7P.*.
> ```

3.

> ```
> P102AH*47
> *HY0P721A
> .7.1*Y0..
> .....2.7.
> ..H.Y.A..
> .0.P.....
> ..P....A.
> .A*Y.1..P
> H21A7P.*.
> ```

4.

> ```
> P102AH*Y7
> *HY0P721A
> .721*Y0PH
> ..A..2.7.
> ..H.Y.A..
> .0.P.....
> .YP....A.
> .A*Y.1..P
> H21A7PY*.
> ```

5.

> ```
> P102AH*Y7
> *HY0P721A
> A721*Y0PH
> ..AH02.7.
> ..H.Y*A..
> .07P.....
> .YP....A.
> .A*Y.1..P
> H21A7PY*0
> ```

6.

> ```
> P102AH*Y7
> *HY0P721A
> A721*Y0PH
> .*AH02.7.
> .PH7Y*A..
> .07P1A...
> .YP..0.A.
> .A*Y.1..P
> H21A7PY*0
> ```

7.

> ```
> P102AH*Y7
> *HY0P721A
> A721*Y0PH
> .*AH02.7.
> .PH7Y*A..
> .07P1AH2.
> 7YP*.01A.
> 0A*Y.1..P
> H21A7PY*0
> ```

8.

> ```
> P102AH*Y7
> *HY0P721A
> A721*Y0PH
> .*AH02P7.
> .PH7Y*A01
> Y07P1AH2.
> 7YP*.01A2
> 0A*Y.17.P
> H21A7PY*0
> ```

9.

> ```
> P102AH*Y7
> *HY0P721A
> A721*Y0PH
> 1*AH02P7Y
> 2PH7Y*A01
> Y07P1AH2*
> 7YP*H01A2
> 0A*Y217HP
> H21A7PY*0
> ```

## Happy New Year too and looking forward to a good year of puzzling for all!

Comment: Your image is missing a symbol in the top row. :) Otherwise, this is the solution.

Comment: @MariaDeleva oh oops! Thanks for pointing that out, will edit...

Comment: And on the bottom row you have "O" instead of "0" :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva so picky :P

Comment: @dcfyj I have upvoted and accepted the answer. :) So it is not a big deal. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva edited to  correct

Comment: Excel? With a [tag:no-computers] tag?

Comment: @randal'thor I didn't run a program to solve it, just used excel as paper to  write on. Can't tell if you are joking if you are then :P

Comment: @randal'thor I doubt Excel solved it for him. :) If it were me, I would have written it on a piece of paper - it would have been easier for me. But as long as he did not use a solver, it is fine with me. :) Solvers kill the fun. :)

Comment: @MariaDeleva adding steps now... (Doing them in batches of 6 moves, so 9 steps here total)

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how to really *explain* the solution of a Sudoku, beyond writing out all the deductions square by square (which would take too long), so I'll express the solution in a series of progress reports. First stop:

> [image: sudoku1]

Fill in all the remaining Ps, As, and 0s (in that order), then the bottom row, a few more bits and pieces, and all the remaining *s, to get:

> [image: sudoku2]

And after the final round of deductions:

> [image]

Which is the solution.

Comment: Beastly was quicker. :) But I have upvoted your answer as well. :)

Comment: @Maria Thanks :-) I hadn't even seen Beastly's answer - was so engrossed in solving this!